# OpenLDAP parametrized replication of a subset

Tags: ldap, query, openldap

I have a huge LDAP database and I'd like to make a replica that contains only a subset of that database. My objective is to replicate a few groups, and all members within that group.

So far, I'm solving that via replicating all groups, and manually inputting user names on the replica filter. This is not ideal, however, because as soon as I add a new user to a group, I have to manually edit the replica filter to include this user, as such:

Before user addition, on replica server:

```
filter="(|(objectClass=posixGroup)(uid=user1)(uid=user2))"
```

After user addition, on replica server:

```
filter="(|(objectClass=posixGroup)(uid=user1)(uid=user2)(uid=NEWuser))"
```

Is there a built-in method to do this task, that is, to replicate a group and all its members?

Otherwise, is there a way to use a "query within a query" (a nested query, if you will), where I use a query result as input to a new query? This way, I'd be able to query who are the members of a group, and select the 'memberOf' results as parameters for the filter. This does seem very convoluted, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a built-in method to do this task, that is, to replicate a group and all its members?

There isn't. But, as you seem to be talking about *specific* groups, you could just use two filters per group, if the "memberof" overlay is enabled:

```
(|(gid=somegroup)(memberOf=somegroup)(gid=othergroup)(memberOf=othergroup))
```

Comment: Good idea. I'm having some trouble enabling the overlay right now, but I'll look into it. Thanks for your input.